Selenium & ChromeDriver & Json WITH PowerShell
I'm trying to figure out how to start with PowerShell and Selenium.
I'm trying that script. Dll are loaded correctly but I think I don't use the correct Json lib.
How to be sure ? Or maybe I'm doing something wrong ? (Tried Json 13.0.0.1 & 13.0.0.3 lib for net45)
My .NET Framework is 4.8.1
Here is the code :
#$ScriptPath = "C:\Selenium\"

# Définir les chemins des DLL et des exécutables
$seleniumWebDriverDir = "C:\NuGet\Packages\Selenium.WebDriver.4.22.0\lib\netstandard2.0"
$chromeDriverDir = "C:\NuGet\Packages\Selenium.WebDriver.ChromeDriver.126.0.6478.6300\driver\win32"
$jsonNetDir = "C:\NuGet\Packages\Newtonsoft.Json.13.0.3\lib\netstandard2.0"

# Trouver les DLL et le driver.exe
$seleniumWebDriverPath = Get-ChildItem -Path $seleniumWebDriverDir -Recurse -Filter "WebDriver.dll" | Select-Object -First 1
$jsonNetPath = Get-ChildItem -Path $jsonNetDir -Recurse -Filter "Newtonsoft.Json.dll" | Select-Object -First 1
$chromeDriverPath = Get-ChildItem -Path $chromeDriverDir -Recurse -Filter "chromedriver.exe" | Select-Object -First 1

# Charger les DLLs nécessaires
try {
    Add-Type -Path $jsonNetPath.FullName
    Write-Output "Newtonsoft.Json.dll OK."
    
    Add-Type -Path $seleniumWebDriverPath.FullName
    Write-Output "WebDriver.dll OK."
} catch {
    Write-Error $_.Exception.Message
}

# Configurer les options pour ChromeDriver
$chromeOptions = New-Object OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome.ChromeOptions
$chromeOptions.BinaryLocation = $chromeDriverPath.FullName

# Initialiser ChromeDriver
try {
    $chrome = New-Object OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome.ChromeDriver($chromeOptions)
    Write-Output "ChromeDriver initialisé avec succès."
} catch {
    Write-Error $_.Exception.Message
}


Error :
 : Exception lors de l'appel de «.ctor» avec «1» argument(s): «Une exception a été levée par l'initialiseur de type pour 
'OpenQA.Selenium.SeleniumManager'.»
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Write-Error], WriteErrorException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WriteErrorException

